# Assign variable only if not nil

Tags: ruby, null, variable-assignment

I have `@obj.items_per_page`, which is `20` at the beginning, and I want the method below to assign value to it only if `many_items` is not `nil`:

```
def fetch_it_baby (many_items = nil)
    @obj.items_per_page = many_items
```

With the code above, even if `many_items` is `nil`, `@obj.items_per_page` remains at `20`. Why? And is that "good" coding? Shouldn't I use something like

```
@obj.items_per_page = many_items || @obj.items_per_page
```

Or is there a third way? I don't feel completely comfortable with either way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The style I generally see looks like this:

```
@obj.items_per_page = many_items if many_items
```

This uses the inline conditional, while avoiding negative or double-negative conditions.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to say the same? Like some crazy attribution signs? It would me nice to have something like `@obj.items_per_page if= many_items`

Answer (score 14):

I suggest the following as it makes it clear that you have a default value for the assignment in case the caller did not specify `many_items` in the call:

```
def function(argument = nil)
  variable = argument || 20
  ...
end
```

However, since you specified that the assignment takes places only if the value is not `nil` then you'll need to check for the `nil` value otherwise you will miss the assignment if the value was `false`.  If you *really* need that case then the solution is more long-winded:

```
def function(argument = nil)
  variable = argument.nil? ? 20 : argument
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `&&=` (in the same way as `||=` is used to assign only if nil or false)

```
> a = 20    # => 20 
> a &&= 30  # => 30
> a         # => 30
> a = nil   # => nil
> a &&= 30  # => nil
> a = false # => false
> a &&= 30  # => false
> a = {}    # => {}
> a &&= 30  # => 30
```

remember though

```
> a = 30      # => 30
> a &&= nil   # => nil
> a &&= false # => nil
> b &&= 3     # => nil
```

Comment: `foobar &&= 3` returns `nil` here. might this have changed since 2015?

Comment: Nope, it behaves as expected, as `foobar = foobar && 3`. The problem is that I was answering to "Assign variable only if *variable* is not nil", whereas the question implied "Assign variable only if *value* is not nil".

Answer (score 10):

> Even if many_items is nil @obj.items_per_page remains at 20

That sounds like whatever class `@obj` is has a custom modifier method `items_per_page=` that only updates the value if the new value is not `nil`.  This is not standard Ruby.  For example, given this definition:

```
class Demo
  attr_accessor :items_per_page
end
```

I get this behavior:

```
irb(main):005:0>     demo = Demo.new           #=> #<Demo:0x007fb7b2060240>
irb(main):006:0>     demo.items_per_page = 20  #=> 20
irb(main):007:0>     demo.items_per_page       #=> 20
irb(main):008:0>     demo.items_per_page = nil #=> nil
irb(main):009:0>     demo.items_per_page       #=> nil
```

As for your example, I would probably write it this way:

```
@obj.items_per_page = many_items unless many_items.nil?
```

Answer (score 4):

For Rails you can also use `presence` as described [here](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence)

```
region = params[:state].presence || params[:country].presence || 'US'
```

Answer (score 0):

[new-alexandria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263858/new-alexandria)'s answer is my go-to, but another "third way" would be to use a [ternary](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Ternary+if):

```
class Demo
  attr_accessor :items_per_page
end

many_items = 100

@obj = Demo.new
@obj.items_per_page = 20  #=> 20
@obj.items_per_page = !many_items.nil? ? 30 : nil   #=> 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Rails and I have a similar need.

You can define a method on your model:

```
class Gift < ApplicationRecord
  def safe_set(attribute, value)
    return if value.nil?
    send("#{attribute}=", value)
  end
end
```

So you can do

```
g = Gift.new
g.colour = 'red'
g.safe_set(:colour, nil)
g.colour  -> 'red'
g.safe_set(:colour, 'green')
g.colour  -> 'green'
```

Answer (score 0):

We have one more method in rails that can help to remove values that are nil.

> compact

This method can be used with an array, hash. Returns the same data removing all values that are nil

Eg :

> array.compact

Further reference:

https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/compact

Answer (score 0):

If many items is a variable the if/unless versions above are the best.  But if many_items is actually a method you don't want to evaluate multiple times I find the following useful.

```
 @obj.items_per_page = many_items.presence || @obj.items_per_page
```

This isn't quite what you want since it won't assign empty strings or other non-nil but non-present values but most of the time I want to do this kind of thing this works for me (it does create a self-assignment when the value is nil/non-present so only use it if your setters are idempotent).